# Can Nautilus search hidden files/directories?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

The search function in Nautilus does not show the hidden files or the files in the hidden directories (like, for example, the Unison .prf files in the directory home/.unison).

There is a way, or a script, to change this behavior? (I have tried also with "gnome-search-tools without any result.

Answer (score 6):

No.

This is [a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/334125) with Nautilus, not only happening in Ubuntu but any distribution using it.

The best way to look for hidden files / folders in your computer will then be via a terminal, ie:

```
find / -name "Kung Fu Panda"
```

So, `find` in `/` any file / folder with `-name` is equal to `Kung Fu Panda`.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your suggestion but I find the results full of things that I don't need (for example a lot of message like "find: "/proc/1358/task/1403/fdinfo": permission denied"). Now I am trying the "locate" command: "locate kung fu panda"

Comment: @mario_user28404 You're getting all those messages because those places aren't owned by you (probably owned by root). You could either use sudo (`sudo find / -name "Kung Fu Panda"`) or limit the search to you home directory (`find ~ -name "Kung Fu Panda"`), which you should own completely.

Comment: Alternatively, use `-iname` if you are not concerned with matching the exact case in your search.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to search on hidden folders or search hidden files, from Ubuntu Software Center install Search Tool (or use `sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool` command). With this tool you can find everything you need.

Comment: `gnome-search-tool` there isn't on Ubuntu 18.04